# most efficient way to parse quoted list of args with spaces inside

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to parse a chatbot string from something like

```
myproject appliances lasthour
```

to

```
("myproject", "appliances", "lasthour")
```

or also

```
myproject appliances "2017-4-13 10:00" "2017-4-13 12:00"
```

to

```
("myproject", "appliances", "2017-4-13 10:00", "2017-4-13 12:00")
```

the issue being the space inside the quoted string. I can probably do it by hand but is the a simpler more maintainable 1 line solution that parses command line args with spaces  in quoted strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`shlex` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) provides shell-style lexical analysis:

```
import shlex
yourstring = '''myproject appliances "2017-4-13 10:00" "2017-4-13 12:00"'''
print repr(shlex.split(yourstring))
```

properly emits:

```
['myproject', 'appliances', '2017-4-13 10:00', '2017-4-13 12:00']
```

Comment: simple response.